# Function decorator that will return self?

Tags: python, instance, decorator, python-decorators, self

I have to following class that will make an object with chainable methods that derive from class variables. Since this code is quite repetitive, my challenge is to make a decorator that can apply over method `a`, `b` and `c`. The problem I am facing is that I cannot seem to find a way to construct a wrapper that will return the instance (`self`). Is there a better way to construct this?

```
class Test:

    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self._a = a
        self._b = b
        self._c = c

        self.call_chain = []


    def a(self, truth):
        def func():
            return self._a == truth
        self.call_chain.append(func)
        return self


    def b(self, truth):
        def func():
            return self._b == truth
        self.call_chain.append(func)
        return self


    def c(self, val):
        def func():
            return self._c == val
        self.call_chain.append(func)
        return self


    def evaluate(self):
        try:
            for f in self.call_chain:
                if f() == False:
                    raise ValueError('False encountered')
        except ValueError:
            self.call_chain.clear()
            return False 
        self.call_chain.clear()
        return True
```

It works chained like this:

```
c = Test(True, False, 13)
c.a(True).b(False).c(13).evaluate()
```

Comment: Can you add a little more info? Not clear why you need a class or decorators to accomplish this. Perhaps some details about the actual problem you're working on - maybe another approach will be more appropriate for your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to store the arguments to the function as part of the call chain.  The easiest way is to use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) objects.

```
from functools import wraps, partial

def chain(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        suspended = partial(func, self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.call_chain.append(suspended)
        return self
    return wrapper

class Test:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.call_chain = []
        self._a = a
        self._b = b
        self._c = c
    @chain
    def a(self, val):
        return self._a == val
    @chain
    def b(self, val):
        return self._b == val
    @chain
    def c(self, val):
        return self._c == val
    def evaluate(self):
        try:
            for f in self.call_chain:
                if f() == False:
                    raise ValueError('False encountered')
        except ValueError:
            self.call_chain.clear()
            return False 
        self.call_chain.clear()
        return True

c = Test(True, False, 13)
c.a(True).b(False).c(13).evaluate()  # True
c.a(True).b(False).c(11).evaluate()  # False
```

Comment: that is interesting, I would've never thought about doing this